# 英語が残っている: ヘルプセンター「メタとは?」で例示されているタグ名

Tags: バグ, 完了

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

> - [support]。サイトの機能についてのサポートのリクエストであることを示します。
> - [bug]。サイト上の再現可能な問題で、ミスや誤動作、またはプログラミング エラーによるものと思われるものを示します。
> - [feature-request]。サイトの新機能の提案、または既存の機能の変更リクエスト。
> - [discussion]。明確な正解や誤答がなく、しばしば主観的であるような投稿。バグや機能リクエストでない場合は、たいていはディスカッションです。

これらのタグは現在のメタでは日本語になっています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

修正案。ついでに説明文も更新。

> - [サポート] サイトの使い方や機能に関して助けを求める時に使います。
> - [バグ] サイト上の不具合や文言が不自然な箇所の報告に使います。
> - [機能の要求] 機能追加や、既存の動作の変更を要望する時に使います。
> - [討議] 必ずしも正解・不正解がなく、主観性がある程度混じるような質問。バグでも機能要望でもない場合は、このタグが適切なことが多いです。